# Reference trade direction in alert message?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a built in way to reference the trade direction in an alert message using the `{{ }}` method? I don't have time to click through and find the right chart after getting a message to find out which it is (trading on short time frames and things move quick); I just want to see it in the alert notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Looking in the reference:

Placeholders with the "strategy" prefix can only be used in strategy alerts:

```
{{strategy.position_size}} - returns the value of the same keyword in Pine, i.e., the size of the current position.
{{strategy.order.action}} - returns the string “buy” or “sell” for the executed order.
{{strategy.order.contracts}} - returns the number of contracts of the executed order.
{{strategy.order.price}} - returns the price at which the order was executed.
{{strategy.order.id}} - returns the ID of the executed order (the string used as the first parameter in one of the function calls generating orders: strategy.entry, strategy.exit or strategy.order).
{{strategy.order.comment}} - returns the comment of the executed order (the string used in the comment parameter in one of the function calls generating orders: strategy.entry, strategy.exit or strategy.order). If no comment is specified, then the value of strategy.order.id will be used.
{{strategy.order.alert_message}} - returns the value of the alert_message parameter which can be used in the strategy's Pine code when calling one of the functions used to place orders: strategy.entry, strategy.exit or strategy.order. This feature is only supported in Pine v4.
**{{strategy.market_position}} - returns the current position of the strategy in string form: “long”, “flat”, or “short”.**
```

Comment: Thanks ok! Now my other issue: I seem to get the same message after the trade closes (which is confusing!). I guess that is why we prefer indicators for alerts over strategies? Or is it possible to suppress that closing message? I can create another question for this but thought a casual ask would be good to start. thanks again =)

Comment: Yeah, that is a disadvantage of using strategies, because once a position closes it is going to send a message that the position is either flat or in another direction.

Comment: {{strategy.order.action}} also returns 'close'no?